# Matlab: Calculate function of each object in an object arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, oop, object

this is my first question so i hope I am doiung the tagging and so on right.

I have an array of objects of the same class. When I want to access a property of the objects I can use:

```
Data = [ObjectArray.property];
```

Now I want to call a mehtod of the class for each object and get back the result as Vektor/ matrice:

```
result = [ObjectArray.myfun(X)]
```

here I get an error saying:

> Expected one output from curly brace or dot indexing expression

I tried brute force several different annotation but nothing works and i can't find a solution online. 
Anybody knows how to make this work?

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly unclear what the structure of your array is, but you should be able to use `arrayfun`.

```
result = arrayfun( @(obj) obj.myfun(x), ObjectArray );
```

If you function `myfun` returns anything other than a scalar, you will need to set the `UniformOutput` flag to be false. This will make the result a cell array, with one cell per result.

```
result = arrayfun( @(obj) obj.myfun(x), ObjectArray, 'uni', false );
% If you want to concatenate results, could use something like
% result = [result{:}];
```

Note that this is basically shorthand for a loop, but it saves you pre-allocating an output and writing the loop.

Comment: Thanks Wolfie! I was hoping that there is a faster solution than a loop, but arrayfun is working.

Comment: @Ray there might well be a faster way, but it depends entirely on your class, the method you're implementing and the structure of your code. With only the info you've given there's no way to offer a tailored solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this directly inside of your myfun:

If the item you operate your method on is an array, the first parameter of your myfun method will be an array. This can be used, and call itself one by one:

```
vec = [MyClass(1), MyClass(2)];
list = vec.myfun();


classdef MyClass
properties
    prop1
end

methods
    function obj = MyClass(val)
        obj.prop1 = val;
    end
    function val = myfun(obj)
       if numel(obj) > 1
           val = arrayfun(@(o) o.myfun(), obj);
           return;
       end
       val = obj.prop1;
    end
end    
end
```